# How to avoid reading parquet files which are in pending status?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, parquet, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using the spark structured-streaming (use *SSS* as abbreviation below) to consume data in kafka and then write them to hdfs in parquet format. Everything seems to works well.
But I find that they share the same filename when writing is going on and finished. This will raise a error when trying to read data in the partitions.

```
path/day=20190924/hour=11/part-00001-0200ea2f-eaff-47ec-8399-8f7e5dfb3c13.c000.snappy.parquet is not a Parquet file.
```

How to avoid this error?
In flink, they will have a tmp filename when writing and rename after finishing the writing.